# Java force stop a thread from executing inside a loop cycle

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on an application using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). As most of the people whom have worked with HtmlUnit knows, that when you have Javascript enabled, it takes a while to load a single page.

My application contains the option to stop the page load, like completely stop all loading and actions.

So I have the Executer class:

```
public class Executer extends Thread {

    private Application app;

    public Executer(Application app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (;;)
            while (app.isRunning()) {
                app.execute();
            }
    }
}
```

Basically this is my executer thread, it calls `app.execute()` every cycle.

So the `execute` method, processes a lot of HtmlUnit orders, such as `getPage()` so htmlunit loads the new page etc.

If the user clicks on Stop button, and then the stop button changes the boolean to false of isRunning, the thread obviously won't stop from executing inside the `execute()` method because it wasn't done executing yet.

I need to find out a way on how to force the thread from executing ANYTHING.

A solution I found was using `executer.stop()` it basically stopped everything that the thread is executing, however `.stop` is deprecated I heard because it just stops everything and some objects may be locked and cause issues.

What solution can I use for this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you **do not want to** use `Thread.Stop()`, than you **MUST** implement special code in your `execute()`-Method which **also** checks the `app.isRunning()`-State.
I am afraid there is no other way to stop the `execute()`-Method.

EDIT:
As mentioned here, the use of `thread.stop();` should be used with care!

Comment: [`Thread.interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) may also be useful.

Comment: `Thread.interrupt` will (as far as i know) only set a FLAG. This flag needs to be checked (`Thread.interrupted()`) by **your** implementation! (very simmilar to Ben Beri's `app.isRunning()`-Flag)

Comment: Some methods throw `InterruptedException` if interruption occurs before or during their execution. Like `Thread.sleep()`, `Object.wait()`. There are also `InterruptibleChannel`s which handle interruptions bit differently, but also allow to break execution of blocking blocks. It is good to know how interruptions work if you are implementing multi-threaded application.

Comment: @NiematojakTomasz blocking blocks are interruptible?

Comment: @eldjon Depends how you define "blocking blocks". And no if I understand correctly. There are some old APIs that are not interruptible designed long time ago where multi-threaded programming wasn't yet so basic thing. Like operations on files - see [RamdomAccessFile.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#read()). Weather some method is interruptible depends on how was it implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't. And there is reason for that - There is no way for java to ensure that application state won't be corrupted if thread is terminated on any instruction it is executing.

For example:

`try(InputStream in = openStream()){
    readStreamContent(in);
}`

If java would terminate thread during execution of `readStreamContent()` the stream would never be closed.

Another example:

`mutex.acquire();
try {
    doSomething();
} finally {
    mutex.release();
}`

If we would terminate thread while in `doSomething()` it would never release `mutex`. This may leave many threads hanging on mutex that would never be released.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `isInterrupted` flag of the `Executor` instance to `true` by calling

```
executor.interrupt()
```

This is the safest way to stop a Thread. when you load a page the thread does not wait actively therefore if it is interrupted while waiting for the server to responde, the executor will stop 
practically right away. Your `Application.isRunning()` is not necessary either as `isInterrupted` flag does exactly the same.

**EDIT:**
Dont ever use Thread.stop() to stop a thread. Its behavior may become unpredictable and in the future 
very difficult to debug if certain unexpected behaviors occur.

Comment: So it is not possible to stop HtmlUnit from executing without modifying the library to check flags, correct?

Comment: Correct. But if that Application is your class you may want to check the isInterrupted flag there.

Comment: @BenBeri Modifying a library doesn't seems to be good idea. Are there any blocking methods which execution you want to interrupt?

Comment: What do you mean? I want to stop client.getPage in htmlunit, etc